# JASPIC Auth Module

Tags: jaspic

we have developed the JASPIC Auth module by implementing the ServerAuthModule interface with the web application, and it is working fine on Tomcat, but when we configure Jaspic on Weblogic (14.1.1), JASPIC behaves unexpectedly. In the case of the Weblogic server, the first call is intercepted by JASPIC, the initialize method is executed, and then the validateRequest method is called. After that, the application home page is served. when we try to move from the home page to another page in the application, JASPIC intercepts the request and calls the initialize method only and not the validateRequest method. In the case of Tomcat, for first request, initialize and then validateRequest method is called and then we move from one page to another page only validateRequest method is calling.
we have added weblogic.xml file in webapp WEB-INF folder, please guide me if any special configuration is required in weblogic.xml for weblogic server